# Change contents of custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to change a custom function variable in an anchor link ecample:

```
<a id="myID" onClick="myFunction(var1, var2, var3);" />
```

I know I can use `$('a#myID').attr('onClick');` to get contents of the onClick event, but how do I change the var3 variable inside that custom function?

Comment: Why not just change the value of that variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it around:

```
<div id="myID">clickable</div>
```

then in JavaScript:

```
$('#myID').click(function () {
    // do stuff with var1 var2 and var whatever
});
```

Comment: This is definitely the best way to do it.

Comment: Going this route.. thanks Mike
Its just my other devs like to yell at me for using anonymous functions  =\

Answer (score 1):

just do a simple:

```
value = $('a#myID').attr('onClick');
value.replace("var1", "blah");
```

Comment: even though i dont understand why somebody would want to do this, you answered exactly his question +1

Comment: yeah I know, I would go with @MikeStewart 's answer personally but I answered in the format the poster requested.